# Accumulate partial reductions into array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

### Problem description

How do I accumulate into `a` the values in `c` using `b` to index into `a`? That is, given

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros(3)
b = np.array([2, 1, 0, 1])
c = np.arange(0.1, 0.5, 0.1)
print ('a=%s b=%s c=%s'.replace(' ', '\n') % (str(a), str(b), str(c)))
```

which outputs

```
a=[ 0.  0.  0.]
b=[2 1 0 1]
c=[ 0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4]
```

how do I achieve

```
d = np.array([0.3, 0.2 + 0.4, 0.1])
print 'd=%s' % str(d)
```

which outputs

```
d=[ 0.3  0.6  0.1]
```

using `a`, `b`, and `c` without using a for loop?

### My solution attempt

I can sort `b` and then sort `c` using the indices that sorted `b`

```
p = b.argsort()
print ('b[p]=%s c[p]=%s'.replace(' ', '\n') % (str(b[p]), str(c[p])))
```

which outputs

```
b[p]=[0 1 1 2]
c[p]=[ 0.3  0.2  0.4  0.1]
```

then reduce `b` to occurrence counts

```
occ = np.bincount(b[p])
print 'occ=%s' % str(occ)
```

which outputs

```
occ=[1 2 1]
```

and use this to compute partials sums

```
print np.array([np.sum(c[p][0:occ[0]]),
                np.sum(c[p][occ[0]:occ[0]+occ[1]]),
                np.sum(c[p][occ[0]+occ[1]:occ[0]+occ[1]+occ[2]])])
```

which outputs

```
[ 0.3  0.6  0.1]
```

How do I generalize this?

### All code and output

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros(3)
b = np.array([2, 1, 0, 1])
c = np.arange(0.1, 0.5, 0.1)
print ('a=%s b=%s c=%s'.replace(' ', '\n') % (str(a), str(b), str(c)))
d = np.array([0.3, 0.2 + 0.4, 0.1])
print 'd=%s' % str(d)
p = b.argsort()
print ('b[p]=%s c[p]=%s'.replace(' ', '\n') % (str(b[p]), str(c[p])))
occ = np.bincount(b[p])
print 'occ=%s' % str(occ)
print np.array([np.sum(c[p][0:occ[0]]),
                np.sum(c[p][occ[0]:occ[0]+occ[1]]),
                np.sum(c[p][occ[0]+occ[1]:occ[0]+occ[1]+occ[2]])])
```

which outputs

```
a=[ 0.  0.  0.]
b=[2 1 0 1]
c=[ 0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4]
d=[ 0.3  0.6  0.1]
b[p]=[0 1 1 2]
c[p]=[ 0.3  0.2  0.4  0.1]
occ=[1 2 1]
[ 0.3  0.6  0.1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.bincount` does exactly what you want:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> b = [2, 1, 0, 1]
>>> c = np.arange(0.1, 0.5, 0.1)
>>> c
array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4])
>>> np.bincount(b, c)
array([0.3, 0.6, 0.1])
```

There is also `np.add.at` but unless the update is very sparse in `a` it is much slower.

```
>>> a = np.zeros(3)
>>> np.add.at(a, b, c)
>>> a
array([0.3, 0.6, 0.1])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use pandas, then solution in one row:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame({'b':b,'c':c}).groupby('b')['c'].sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
b  c
0 0.3 
1 0.6 
2 0.1
```

If you need then numpy array, wrap up the nessecery column to numpy:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame({'b':b,'c':c}).groupby('b')['c'].sum().reset_index()
b = np.array(a['b'])
c = np.array(a['c'])
```

Comment: Nice, but can it be done in numpy? I ask because I'm not currently using pandas so it would add a new dependency to my project.